# Set lxml etree text to string with tags

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have a problem regarding the lxml.etree library.
I have a string like

```
string = "this<a/>is<b/>nice"
```

and I want to set this string as the text of an element node.

```
node.text = string
```

But everytime if I print out the text of the node, its escaped like this:

```
"this&lt;a\&gt;is&lt;b\&gt;nice"
```

So how do I set the text so that its not escaped anymore? I cant do it e.g. with node.tail or anything, because I have more than one node inside the text.

Comment: Is it really supposed to be text in an element, or do you want the `<a/>` and `<b/>` to be added as child elements? If it's supposed to be unescaped text, you can add it as [CDATA](https://lxml.de/api.html#cdata).

Comment: Yes it would be nice if they are subchildren, but I dont know how I can do that with the text in between the tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is add a root element to the string to make it well-formed and then parse it using `tostring()`. Then you can add the Element as a child of the target element.

Once it's where it's supposed to be, you can use [`strip_tags()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_tags) to remove the temporary root element.

Example...

**Python**

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.fromstring("<doc/>")

print(f"doc before: \"{etree.tostring(doc).decode()}\"")

string = "this<a/>is<b/>nice"

fragment = etree.fromstring(f"<temp>{string}</temp>")
doc.append(fragment)
etree.strip_tags(doc, "temp")

print(f"doc after: \"{etree.tostring(doc).decode()}\"")
```

**Console Output**

```
doc before: "<doc/>"
doc after: "<doc>this<a/>is<b/>nice</doc>"
```